# Exponential system of equations

Tags: exponential-function, systems-of-equations

Find $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{align*}
2^x+3^y=7, \\
2^y+3^x=11
\end{align*}
Obviously, $(x,y)=(2,1)$ is a solution, but I can't prove that it's the only one. I tried using contradiction arguments, monotony, convexity and $\log$s, but didn't succed.

Comment: eliminate one variable from the given system

Comment: This is similar to the Ramanujan school problem. In case you are wondering what the problem was, it concerned to the solutions of : $$\sqrt {x}+y =7$$ $$\sqrt {y }+x =11$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner when I eliminate one variable, I get $\log_{2}3=\log_{7-3^y}(11-2^y)$

Comment: i got this here $${2}^{{\frac {\ln  \left( -{2}^{x}+7 \right) }{\ln  \left( 3 \right) }}
}+{3}^{x}-11
=0$$